# Can't get modificationset to work in CruiseControl on Linux

Tags: linux, cruisecontrol

I am trying to setup cruisecontrol in a Linux environment.  I have some experience with cc.NET, but this is the first time I have ever tried to use the 'nix  version.  This is what I have for my build.xml:

When I run "ant project1", everything seems to work except that it tells me:
/opt/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/projects/portal/build.xml:8: Problem: failed to create task or type modificationset
Cause: The name is undefined.

I can't seem to find another way to say "only build when a change is checked into svn."  I am using CC 2.8.3.  Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project1" basedir=".">
 <target name="checkout">
    <exec executable="svn" dir="${basedir}/source">
      <arg line="up" />
    </exec>
 </target>
 <modificationset>
    <svn localWorkingCopy="projects/${project.name}/source/"/>
 </modificationset>
 <target name="php-codesniffer">
    <exec executable="phpcs"
          dir="${basedir}/source"
          output="${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml">
          <arg line="--report=checkstyle
                 --standard=PEAR
                 --ignore=src/autoload src/"/>
    </exec>
 </target>
 <target name="publish">
 </target>
 <target name="build" depends="checkout,php-codesniffer" />
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... I don't quite follow your setup. The XML file you posted is supposed to be an ANT build file or CruiseControl XML configuration file?

Because these two are different.
`<target>s` usually show up in [the ANT file](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html), while `<modificationset>` is something typical for [CruiseControl configuration](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html). By accident they both use `<project>` element.

So I would suggest you moving the `<modificationset>` to CC config file. There's an option as well to tell CC to build only when any modifications are found (isn't it the default setting?).

EDIT: And BTW, the issue doesn't seem to have anything in common with Unix per se. I tend to believe you would run into the same problems on Windows.

Comment: Got it.  I didn't realize there were two files we were dealing with!

Answer (score 0):

For continuous building I use cronjob and this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd myLocalWorkingCopy
if [[ \"`/usr/bin/svn info -r HEAD`\" = \"`/usr/bin/svn info -r BASE`\" ]]; then
  echo "local working copy up to date"
else
  /usr/bin/nant -buildfile:myBuildfile.build -logfile:myLogfile.log
fi
```

I hope this helps...